# Why does Ubuntu install continue to fail with 'grub-install /dev/sda failed' error?

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, system-installation, uefi

**Goal**: I am trying to install Ubuntu onto a [Dell XPS 8900](https://dl.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_xps_desktop/xps-8900-desktop_reference%20guide_en-us.pdf).

**Problem**: I can't get through an Ubuntu install without the install interrupting with `Unable to install Grub in /dev/sda`, `Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda failed.' This is a fatal error.`. Moreover `boot-repair` doesn't fix the issue.

**Installer**: I am using a flash drive with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Installer on it. I have tried with a flash drive that I have installed with before and I have tried with a fresh install on another flash drive that I created with the Startup Disk Creator application. [Note: I have added nomodeset and acpi=off in my grub command to start the Ubuntu Installer OS.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312786/ubuntu-18-lts-20-lts-freeze-on-boot-from-usb)

**Attempts to solve**:

- I tried to complete the grub-install myself using some [answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254491/failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-cow) on askubuntu. I did the aforementioned *fix* by exiting the installer prompt (after it failed) and running the commands in the terminal. I was able to successfully complete the grub-install here. However, as the original error happens part way into an install the resulting Ubuntu OS had multiple problems. I had services that would fail or just not start (including but not limited to: networkd-dispatcher.service, NetworkManager.service, fwupd-refresh.service, apparmor.service, caspermd5.services(?) ) and I had left over remnants from the install (for example, an [application named Install RELEASE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285304/what-exactly-is-install-release-how-to-get-rid-of-it) was still in my applications).

  - Note: `chroot`ing into `/mnt` and running `grub-install /dev/sda` results in `unable to allocate pty: No such device`
- [Top answer here] (https://askubuntu.com/questions/143678/i-receive-the-error-grub-install-dev-sda-failed-while-attempting-to-install-u) suggests clicking Try Ubuntu and then using the Install Ubuntu 24.04 LTS application, which didn't work for me.
- [Top answer here] (https://askubuntu.com/questions/459620/unable-to-install-grub-in-dev-sda-when-installing-grub) suggests that grub-install is installing to the wrong device, which isn't true for me.
- I am desperate now, so I updated the BIOS to its most recent update. That didn't do anything.
- I tried running grub-install prior to running the Try Install application.

  - Note: running `sudo grub-install --root-directory /mnt /dev/sda` results in `grub-instal: error: failed to register the EFI boot entry: Operation not permitted.`
  - Also, I worry that even if I could successfully run grub-install prior to running the Ubuntu Installer, that the Ubuntu Installer would still fail because the Ubuntu Installer might run grub-install without options.
- `boot-repair` said that the NVram was locked. I saw [a suggestion to clear the NVRAM](https://forum.zorin.com/t/error-nvram-is-locked/17150) by [resetting the CMOS](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/xps-8900-desktop/xps-8900-desktop/procedure?guid=guid-e7cb0968-2c3c-4970-8a47-b70b169f3f35&lang=en-us). After resetting the CMOS, I still get the same error message during installation.

**Question**: Why does Ubuntu 22.04 LTS install continue to fail with 'grub-install /dev/sda failed' error?

**Result of `boot-info`**:

- https://pastebin.com/tLfzEF8w
- https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BQNbny9528/

**Result of `boot-repair`**:

- https://pastebin.com/z4ftZ8mW
- https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Shc4V4xB9T

Comment: the paste.ubuntu link requires a login ... add the text instead

Comment: @jsotola I added a different pastebin just for you :)

Comment: are you able not to run installing but just launch Ubuntu? Launch it, then open gparted and paste here what it shows.

Comment: What brand/model system? Some have UEFI settings preventing new entries to ESP - efi system partition. Check UEFI settings. You may need manual as brief description in UEFI is brief. One example: Lenovo Thinkpad E531 - turn off locked boot order setting in UEFI
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2255746

Comment: @Andra Can't do that right now, hopefully the information you are looking for should be in the boot-info pastebin above. Let me know if not.

Comment: @oldfred [Dell XPS 8900](https://dl.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_xps_desktop/xps-8900-desktop_reference%20guide_en-us.pdf)

Comment: when you install, what do you choose for "Device for boot loader installation"? But maybe this is shown only if you choose Installation type>Something else.

Comment: @Andra, Yeah, I haven't tried choosing Installation type > Something else. I choose Erase and reinstall.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI to latest available from Dell. Or even reflashed most current version. Some have posted that may help. Some other posts have total reset of UEFI/BIOS by removing coin battery, but that resets everything to defaults and you have to redo all settings you changed & reinstall boot loaders.

Comment: @oldfred I did update the BIOS. What are your thoughts on the [suggestion to clear the NVRAM](https://forum.zorin.com/t/error-nvram-is-locked/17150) by [resetting the CMOS](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/xps-8900-desktop/xps-8900-desktop/procedure?guid=guid-e7cb0968-2c3c-4970-8a47-b70b169f3f35&lang=en-us)?

Comment: As long as you know what settings to redo in UEFI and have Ubuntu live installer, so you can reinstall grub with Boot-Repair or chroot. If you have Windows, you also need a Windows repair flash drive. I have an old BIOS laptop where coin battery has died. I can boot in BIOS mode, but have to reset clock and some other settings, every time I plug it back into main power.

Comment: @oldfred I'm not worried about losing any of the data on the HDD (or settings in the UEFI). So you think the "clearing NVram" route is viable solution? Is this [clearing settings option](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/xps-8900-desktop/xps-8900-desktop/procedure?guid=guid-e7cb0968-2c3c-4970-8a47-b70b169f3f35&lang=en-us) different than pulling the CMOS battery out (or are they essentially the same)?

By the way, I should mention that this computer was sitting in a closet for 2 years without any power (but i'm not sure if this affects the CMOS battery...).

Comment: Often jumper is first choice. I have used it once or twice. If that does not reset things, then removing coin battery. I really hate those little tiny jumpers as "old" in oldfred does not see as well as he used to, and even then I hated them.

Comment: @oldfred Ok, I'll give it a try. I'm unsure if I should move the pins while the computer is off or on.

Comment: @oldfred, I successfully cleared the CMOS settings, but the Ubuntu installation still failed with `Unable to install Grub in /dev/sda, Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda failed.' This is a fatal error.`

Comment: Always have power off when working inside system. No locked error? Can you write into ESP if you mount it? You may need dosfsck? You are installing in UEFI mode and have an ESP, FAT32 with boot,esp flags? https://askubuntu.com/questions/862724/grub2-failed-to-install/86587z682#865872

Comment: @oldfred I just tried `boot-repair` again. Got the exact same result as the previous `boot-repair` run... NVram Locked!

I ran `dosfsck` in verbose mode. There does not seem to be any problem with the FAT filesytem. I can successfully mount and write into the ESP.

I am in UEFI mode (I have yet to try legacy mode in the BIOS).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139584/discussion-between-mrdrago9-and-oldfred).

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled into the very same issue - failed to install 20.04LTS and 22.04LTS.

I eventually fixed this: After Ubuntu installer failed, reboot into USB live Ubuntu and re-run boot-repair. It worked out marvelously.

To be more specifically:

- I have 2 Nvidia 3090 graphic card.
- After selecting "Install Ubuntu" in GRUB menuu, I got a black screen. So I have to press `e` on GRUB menu add `acpi=off` (`nomodeset` or choosing "Safe Graphic" didn't help in my case) to get into USB live Ubuntu to install.
- Then I meet this *"Failed to install GRUB to NVMe"*, and runing boot-repair result in "*NVram locked"*.

  I assume that during the previous installation, my SSD somehow was added a lock, so boot-repair can't do any changes and instead I get *"NVram locked"*. If you run `cd /target`, you will go straight into it.
- After a reboot, run `cd /target`, you will get a `not a directory` error message.
  Then run boot-repair. Problem solved.

I also tried to install GRUB manually, following AskUbuntu posts. But I'm not a native English speaker, so I suppose I messed up which is which, what drive I should mount. Can't really figure out if the word 'device/hardware/drive' means USB stick or SSD.

Answer (score 0):

`NVram Locked` sounds like there might be some problems writing into the UEFI NVRAM variables, which are accessible in Linux via `/sys/firmware/efivars` or using the `efibootmgr` tool.

If you are accessing the failed installation by mounting it under `/mnt/chrootdir` and `chroot`ing into it as suggested in answers to the [AskUbuntu question you linked](https://askubuntu.com/q/254491/769591), I would suggest using `mount --rbind` instead of `mount --bind` for both `/dev` and `/sys`, as both include separate sub-filesystems that can be important for `grub-install` functionality:

- if `/dev/pts` is not available in the chrooted environment, it would cause the `unable to allocate pty: No such device` error
- if `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` is not available in the chrooted environment, it would cause the attempts to write into UEFI NVRAM variables to fail... which is exactly your primary issue.

But if this does not help, you might want to read [this excellent webpage by Roderick W. Smith](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html), which explains certain problems other OSs or buggy UEFI firmware implementations can cause, and gives methods for working around them.

On your `sda1` disk, there is apparently a `efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg` file, with the following contents:

```
search.fs_uuid 2D07-0F0A root hd0,gpt1 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

This seems incorrect: it is looking for the ESP partition (`sda1`) by filesystem UUID, and then assuming it should be a Linux root filesystem that contains `/boot/grub`... which is not true, as `sda1` is the UEFI ESP, not the Linux root filesystem.

That file should instead have the following contents:

```
search.fs_uuid 25f0e88-f20a-4350-9df0-ee8c57ecc455 root hd0,gpt2
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

You might want to copy this `efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg` to `efi/BOOT/grub.cfg` (also on `sda1`) too, to allow GRUB to find a valid configuration even if started as `efi/BOOT/BOOTx64.efi`.

This configuration file would cause the `grubx64.efi` on the ESP to seek the real Ubuntu root partition (`sda2`) by filesystem UUID, and then load any necessary GRUB modules from there, and also load the true GRUB configuration from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` on `sda2`.

You might also want to copy `efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` into `efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi` on `sda1`, to ensure the full set of boot files are also available on the UEFI fallback/removable media boot path.

This part of the boot-repair output is actually produced by `efibootmgr -v`:

```
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0004
Boot0003* UEFI: TOSHIBA TransMemory 1.00    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(1,0)/HD(2,GPT,9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a12-46dc207b42ee,0x71e8a0,0x2130)..BO
Boot0004* UEFI: ST2000DM001-1ER164  HD(1,GPT,22c1dbaf-a26e-4408-a6f9-d1fc06b0d615,0x800,0x100000)/File(EFI\boot\bootx64.efi)..BO
```

It indicates that although you've currently booted from USB, your system firmware is prepared to boot from `sda1` (identified by PARTUUID `2c1dbaf-a26e-4408-a6f9-d1fc06b0d615` using the file fallback/removable media boot path `EFI/boot/bootx64.efi` (the filesystem on ESP is `vfat`, so it *should* be case-insensitive... but some UEFI firmware implementations aren't). So if you can perform the above-mentioned changes to the ESP, the system might be able to boot from `sda1`.

If you can get a regular Ubuntu system running in UEFI mode, you could retry `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` to rewrite the bootloader and automatically re-write the NVRAM boot variable for Ubuntu. Or alternatively, you could use the `efibootmgr` command to try and precision-fix just the boot variable issue yourself:

```
sudo efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -l \\EFI\\ubuntu\\grubx64.efi -L Ubuntu
```

(This command requires that `/dev/sda1` is mounted as `/boot/efi` and the `efivarfs` filesystem is mounted at `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars`. Both of these conditions should be handled automatically by a normal Ubuntu boot process.)

If this still fails with "NVram Locked" or similar, you might have a buggy UEFI implementation, but at least it allows you to boot into Ubuntu by using the fallback/removable media path.